# How does react-router keep components from unmounting with route changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I will preface this by saying that everything works correctly, it's just that I'm trying to understand what is happening exactly and why I'm seeing this behavior.

Say I have a component, `FooComponent`, and two different routes, `/foo` and `/bar`. I'm rendering them as follows:

```js
<Route
    exact
    path="/foo"
    render={({ location }) => <FooComponent location={location} />}
/>
<Route
    path="/bar"
    render={({ location }) => <FooComponent location={location} />}
/>
```

When clicking between pages `/foo` and `/bar`, it seems that `FooComponent` mounts only once. To test this, here's how the `FooComponent` is implemented:

```js
const FooComponent = ({ location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mount");
    return () => {
      console.log("Cleanup");
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>At {location.pathname}</div>;
};
```

`Mount` is only logged once.

This completely puzzles me as `FooComponent` is rendered by two completely different parent `Route` components, and I thought React would only perform reconciliation on same parent component re-rendering with different child elements. Moreover, changing one to return `<div><FooComponent location={location} /></div>` and leaving the other as-is will cause the component to unmount.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-golick-86rxm?file=/src/App.js) is the reproducible example.

Comment: maybe should be how react-router-dom work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like what you mentioned, I believe this behavior is mostly related to React Reconciliation process. Whenever the root elements have different types, in our case `<div />` vs `<FooComponent />`, React will create a new tree. That's why we are seeing the unmount event.

In the following case, the prop (location) for `FooComponent` will be changed when we go to a different route. Because we have two React DOM elements of the same type, React will only update and re-render the component.

```js
// location is changed by react-route
<Route
    exact
    path="/foo"
    render={({ location }) => <FooComponent location={location} />}
/>
<Route
    path="/bar"
    render={({ location }) => <FooComponent location={location} />}
/>


const FooComponent = ({ location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mount");
    return () => {
      console.log("Cleanup");
    };
  }, []);
  
  // the parent components is the same, only the child node of the following div is chnaged, so React rerenders the div.
  return <div>At {location.pathname}</div>;
};
```

On the react-router side, `Route` doesn't change the DOM structure, if you look at the source code. it only acts as a context provider.

```js
return (
            <RouterContext.Provider value={props}>
              {props.match
                ? children
                  ? typeof children === "function"
                    ? __DEV__
                      ? evalChildrenDev(children, props, this.props.path)
                      : children(props)
                    : children
                  : component
                  ? React.createElement(component, props)
                  : render
                  ? render(props)
                  : null
                : typeof children === "function"
                ? __DEV__
                  ? evalChildrenDev(children, props, this.props.path)
                  : children(props)
                : null}
            </RouterContext.Provider>
          );
```

References:

[react-dom/Router.js](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js)

[React/Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

basically I think that React optimizes on the basic concept that two equal stateless components are equivalent in computing the DOM output.
Changing key prop, you can explicit specify that the components should be remounted:

```
<Route exact path="/foo" render={({ location }) => <FooComponent key='1' location={location} />} />
<Route path="/bar" render={({ location }) => <FooComponent key='2' location={location} />} />
```